# How to use curl_blob in libcurl/ c++?

Tags: c++, libcurl

I am trying to use libcurl with c++ and to make requests with mTLS (mutual TLS/ Two Way TLS). Passing the certificates as file paths works. But I would like to use embeded certificates in the source code and not external files. I discovered `BLOB` options in the curl lib website ([example](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SSLCERT_BLOB.html))

There is also an example on the website where `curl_blob` struct has been used:

```cpp
CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl) {
  struct curl_blob stblob;
  stblob.data = certificateData; // What to pass here (e.g. from a string)
  stblob.len = filesize; // What about here?
  stblob.flags = CURL_BLOB_COPY;
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.com/");
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSLCERT_BLOB, &stblob);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE, "P12");
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_KEYPASSWD, "s3cret");
  ret = curl_easy_perform(curl);
  curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}
```

How to make use of `curl_blob` struct and its attributes?

Comment: What is not clear in the first paragraph of the description on the linked page?

Comment: What is `certificateData`? Is that a `string`, a `char*`, a `byte array` ? This may sound weird, but I come from a Java background. So bear with me here :)

Comment: This is a pointer `void*` to the data in P12 format, is rather a byte array.

Comment: Could you give me a working example? I have read about it and I know that `void*` is a pointer whose data type is not known. But how is the data of the P12 or PEM file passed?

Comment: This is a raw content of the certificate file.p12.

Comment: Could you please be more specific? How should I approach this? Read the file into a char array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution.

`stdblob.data` requires a `char*` with the file/string content.
`stblob.len` requires the length of the string/char array.

This is a simple example:

```cpp
    char* str_to_char_arr(string str)
    {
        const int n = str.length() + 1;

        char* char_array = new char[n + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            char_array[i] = str[i];

        return char_array;
    }

    std::string client_cert_content =
        "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n"
        "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
        "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
        ".....\n"
        "-----END CERTIFICATE-----";

    curl_blob get_client_cert()
    {
        struct curl_blob stblob;
        stblob.data = str_to_char_arr(client_cert_content);
        stblob.len = client_cert_content.length();
        stblob.flags = CURL_BLOB_COPY;

        return stblob;
    }
```

And then add the cert this way:

```cpp
struct curl_blob client_cert_blob = get_client_cert();
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSLCERT_BLOB, &client_cert_blob);
```

I wanted to use embeded certificates, and this way worked. But the same logic works when reading the char array from a file.